# Issue with QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC") Qt 4.8.4

Tags: sql-server, qt, odbc

Im trying to connect to a remote SQL Server database. When trying to add "QODBC" as my QSqlDatabase, I get the following error on the runtime:

My Code snippet:

```
               QStringList drivers = QSqlDatabase::drivers();
               qDebug()<<"drivers list: "<<drivers;
               QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
```

Error:

```
         drivers list:  ("QODBC3", "QODBC") 
         Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x40804) with this library (version 0x40803)
```

As you can see the output of my drivers list shows that I have the drivers available. The .pro file has "QT += sql", I have followed the instructions on QT support blog to build the odbc drivers and added them to my application folder as "sqldrivers" sub folder. I can't seem to find how do I solve the Version Incompatibility error. Any help in resolving this issue will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your QODBC library is incompatible with your Qt library， maybe you should build QODBC library with your qt version. There is a guide: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html

Comment: I followed the guide to build the QOBDC sqldrivers in the first place.  Not sure how to remove the older version.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The issue was the QtCore & QtGui dll's in my application release folder was a older qt 4.8.3, changed this to the current qt 4.8.4.